# Perl sub skips foreach within which it is called

Tags: perl

I'm having some problem with a subroutine that locates certain files and extracts some data out of them.

This subroutine is called inside a foreach loop, but whenever the call is made the loop skips to its next iteration. So I am wondering whether any of the next;'s are somehow escaping from the subroutine to the foreach loop where it is called?

To my knowledge the sub looks solid though so I'm hoping if anyone can see something I'm missing?

```
sub FindKit{
    opendir(DH, "$FindBin::Bin\\data");
    my @kitfiles = readdir(DH);
    closedir(DH);

    my $nametosearch = $_[0];
    my $numr = 1;
    foreach my $kitfile (@kitfiles)
    {
        # skip . and .. and Thumbs.db and non-K-files
        if($kitfile =~ /^\.$/) {shift @kitfiles; next;}
        if($kitfile =~ /^\.\.$/) {shift @kitfiles; next;}
        if($kitfile =~ /Thumbs\.db/) {shift @kitfiles; next;}
        if($kitfile =~ /^[^K]/) {shift @kitfiles; next;}

        # $kitfile is the file used on this iteration of the loop
        open (my $fhkits,"<","data\\$kitfile") or die "$!";
        while (<$fhkits>) {}
        if ($. <= 1) {
            print " Empty File!";
            next;
        }
        seek($fhkits,0,0);
        while (my $kitrow = <$fhkits>) {
            if ($. == 0 && $kitrow =~ /Maakartikel :\s*(\S+)\s+Montagekit.*?($nametosearch)\s{3,}/g) {
                close $fhkits;
                return $1;
            }
        }
        $numr++;
        close $fhkits;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (1) Are some of the variables in the subroutine global (or at least seen in the enclosing scope)?  Something can get set which triggers code in the caller to skip its loop.  For one thing, there is that `$numr` which gets incremented (or not), but is not used anywhere. (2) Can the return `($1)` cause the calling code to skip its iteration?

Comment: I've already checked whether the variables are used elsewhere. And the sub is called using $foundkit = &FindKit($name);, so it sets $foundkit to $1 but this variable is used elsewhere: not within the problematic foreach that is getting skipped.

Comment: This code needs a complete rewrite.  (1) When you `shift` you remove _the next_ element.  That doesn't seem to be the intent (Try: `perl -E'@ary = 1..10; for (@ary) { say; shift @ary }`) (2) if you want to skip `.`  you do `next if $kitfile eq '.';` (same for `..`) (3) Read the whole file to see whether it's empty?  (And it allows one line in fact!)  That's what [`-z`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) is for (for which you don't even have to open the file). (4) Instead of the last `while` -- read one line and do your condition, then count `$numr++ while <$fh>` (then add 1);

Comment: Another one: of all four (4) conditions to skip only the last one need stay: We skip if the first letter of file/dir name is not K -- but this _includes_ all others (neither of `.` and `..` and `Thumbs.db` start with `K`).  Once we are at it -- you want only files that start with `K`? Then I'd go for `my @files = glob "K*"`.  Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: (These comments are intended to be helpful and constructive -- not mean :)

Comment: They're interpreted as helpful too, I'm looking into improving the code now. Just to note: Empty files may contain just a header-line and no data, which is why I allowed a single line. And the code has worked fine on its own to list the files within a folder (numr is actually a remnant of this that I should remove now, as it was only there to number the listed files). And you are completely right on three of the four skips being redundant.

Comment: Oh, I missed this: `$.` starts from `1`.  So the `if ($. == 0 ...` is _never_ true, so this sub should always return `0`.

Comment: Yes, I suggest a nice cleanup.  None of this should cause the _caller_ to skip its loop though, by what you say about the return not being used.  Nothing that I can see that is.

Comment: What is the chance of `Maakartikel` being in that header line?

Comment: My perl file is in the folder before the data folder, so $Find::Bin\\data returns the path to the data folder. Maakartikel is always in the header. I'm going to clean this up and see if that makes it easier to figure this out

Comment: That  `/g` modified in the regex `/.../g` is useless -- and potentially dangerous here.  The code needs one match, it will search the whole string for it.

Comment: The caller code would be needed to diagnose this.

Comment: @zdim: *"When you shift you remove* **the next** *element"* No. `shift` always removes the *first* element from the array, regardless of where the iteration has reached.

Comment: @Borodin  Oh, of course!  It _skips_ (processing of) the next element, since `for` picks the next position.  It's so unpleasant to think through that I'd never `shift` in a `for` loop.  Thank you for correcting that.  (I try to be careful, but these things do slip in :(

Comment: @zdim: No worries. The entire design of SO is based on mutual correction and improvement. You're not expected to get things right every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize comments, the refactored code:

```
use File::Glob ':bsd_glob';

sub FindKit {
    my $nametosearch = $_[0];

    my @kitfiles = glob "$FindBin::Bin/data/K*";  # files that start with K
    foreach my $kitfile (@kitfiles)
    {
        open my $fhkits, '<', $kitfile or die "$!";

        my $kitrow_first_line = <$fhkits>;    # read first line

        return if eof;  #  next read is end-of-file so it was just header

        my ($result) = $kitrow_first_line =~ 
            /Maakartikel :\s*(\S+)\s+Montagekit.*?($nametosearch)\s{3,}/;

        return $result if $result;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I use core [File::Glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html) and enable `:bsd_glob` option, which can handle spaces in filenames. I follow the docs note to use "*real slash*" on Win32 systems.

I check whether there is only a header line using [eof](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof).<sup>†</sup>

I do not see how this can affect the calling code, other than by its return value.   Also, I don't see how the posted code can make the caller skip the beat, either.  That problem is unlikely to be in this sub.

Please let me know if I missed some point with the above rewrite.

---

<sup>†</sup>  Previous version used to check whether there is just one (header) line by

```
1 while <$fhkits>;    # check number of lines ...
return if $. == 1;    # there was only one line, the header
```

Also correct but `eof` is way better

Comment: the `glob "$FindBin::Bin/data/K*"` returns full path names. e.g. you don't need specify the `data` directory in the `open`... (`open (my $fhkits,"<","data\\$kitfile")`. Aren't?

Comment: The thing that I'm pretty sure is causing 'skipping loop' will be modifying `@kitfiles` as it's being iterated, as that `shift` is just pulling the first element off the array and moving everything else 'up' - so it'll miss things.

Comment: @jm666  Thank you! Corrected.  (I lifted that line from OP while I changed their `opendir` to `glob`, and I even remarked on that in a comment ... and now introduced a bug :)

Comment: @Sobrique  That's wrong, I agree, and I stated it in comments.  But I don't see how it can cause it to skip the _caller's_ loop.  (It's a loop in the calling code that's getting skipped!)

Comment: Without seeing the caller's loop, or expected behaviour, it's really hard to say. I'd imagine that having something that should match, but mysteriously doesn't might look quite similar though. Given the egregious logic errors in this 'looks ok' subroutine, I wouldn't be confident that the caller was any better.

Comment: @Sobrique  It reads a directory, closes it, and processes files.  Skipping some files can't cause it to skip an iteration in the calling code.  As for the expected behavior, I too raised that in a comment -- they say the return isn't used in that loop.  I don't see anything in their code, other than the `0` return (explained in yet another comment, due to expecting `$.` to start at 0).  Now it's all corrected, so we'll see.

Comment: @Zyzyx Fixed a bug, curtesy of jm666's observation.  Once `glob` is used it returns full-path names so there is no need for `data` directory when opening the file.  (And with it it wouldn't find any files.)

Comment: @zdim: *"We use core `File::Glob` which overrides the system's `glob`"*  [perldoc glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) says **This operator is implemented using the standard `File::Glob` extension**. What you have done is to enable the `:bsd_glob` option, which allows embedded spaces inside file name patterns.

Comment: @Borodin  Oh.  Thank you again.  I didn't realize that distinction.  Correcting...

Answer (score 1):

The thing that is almost certainly screwing you here, is that you are `shift`ing the list that you are iterating.

That's bad news, as you're deleting elements ... but in places you aren't necessarily thinking.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = qw ( one two three ); 
my $count;

foreach my $value ( @list ) {
   print "Iteration ", ++$count," value is $value\n";
   if ( $value eq 'two' ) { shift @list; next };
}

print "@list";
```

How many times do you think that should iterate, and which values should end up in the array?

Because you `shift` you never process element 'three' and you delete element 'one'. That's almost certainly what's causing you problems.

You also:

- `open` using a relative path, when your `opendir` used an absolute one.
- skip a bunch of files, and then skip anything that doesn't start with `K`. Why not just search for things that *do* start with `K`?
- read the file twice, and one is to just check if it's empty. The [perl file test `-z`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) will do this just fine.
- you set `$kitrow` for each line in the file, but don't really use it for anything other than pattern matching. It'd probably work better using implicit variables.
- You only actually do anything on the first line - so you don't ever need to iterate the whole file. (`$numr` seems to be discarded).
- you use a global match, but only use one result. The `g` flag seems redundant here.

I'd suggest a big rewrite, and do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin;

sub FindKit{
    my ($nametosearch) = @_;

    my $numr = 1;
    foreach my $kitfile (glob "$FindBin::Bin\\data\\K*" )
    {
       if ( -z $kitfile ) {
           print "$kitfile is empty\n";
           next;
        }

        # $kitfile is the file used on this iteration of the loop
        open (my $fhkits,"<", $kitfile) or die "$!";
        <$kitfile> =~ m/Maakartikel :\s*(\S+)\s+Montagekit.*?($nametosearch)\s{3,}/ 
             and return $1; 
        return 0; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a big fan of the [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) module (me have it always installed and using it in every project) my solution would be:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny;

my $found = FindKit('mykit');
print "$found\n";

sub FindKit {
    my($nametosearch) = @_;

    my $datadir = path($0)->realpath->parent->child('data');
    die "$datadir doesn't exists" unless -d $datadir;

    for my $file ($datadir->children( qr /^K/ )) {
        next if -z $file; #skip empty
        my @lines = $file->lines;
        return $1 if $lines[0] =~ /Maakartikel :\s*(\S+)\s+Montagekit.*?($nametosearch)\s{3,}/;
    }
    return;
}
```

Some comments and still opened issues:

- Using the [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) you could always use forward slashes in the path-names, regardless of the OS (UNIX/Windows), e.g. the `data/file` will work on windows too.
- AFAIK the FindBin is [considered broken](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=41213) - so the above uses the `$0` and `realpath` ...
- what if the Kit is in multiple files? The above always returns on the 1st found one
- the `my @lines = $file->lines;` reads all lines - unnecessary - but on small files doesn't big deal.
- the the reality this function returns the arg for the `Maakartikel`, so probably better name would be `find_articel_by_kit` or `find_articel` :)
- easy to switch to `utf8` - just change the `$file->lines` to `$file->lines_utf8;`

Comment: It's nopt safe to use `$0` for this purpose; firstly because its initial contents vary from system to system, and secondly because can be modified, and so may be completely different from the name of the program file. It's much better to `use FindBin ()` and `"$FindBin::Bin/$FindBin::Script"`.